# BayesSearchCV ValueError: All integer values shouldbe greater than 0.000000

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, bayesian, scikit-optimize

I'm trying to tune an xgboost model with BayesSearchCV for multiclass classification. Here's my code.

```
n_iterations = 50

estimator = xgb.XGBClassifier(
    n_jobs=-1,
    objective="multi:softmax",
    eval_metric="merror",
    verbosity=0,
    num_class=3)

search_space = {
    "learning_rate": (0.01, 1.0, "log-uniform"),
    "min_child_weight": (0, 10),
    "max_depth": (1, 50),
    "max_delta_step": (0, 10),
    "subsample": (0.01, 1.0, "uniform"),
    "colsample_bytree": (0.01, 1.0, "log-uniform"),
    "colsample_bylevel": (0.01, 1.0, "log-uniform"),
    "reg_lambda": (1e-9, 1000, "log-uniform"),
    "reg_alpha": (1e-9, 1.0, "log-uniform"),
    "gamma": (1e-9, 0.5, "log-uniform"),
    "min_child_weight": (0, 5),
    "n_estimators": (5, 5000),
    "scale_pos_weight": (1e-6, 500, "log-uniform"),
}

cv = GroupKFold(n_splits=10)
#cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True)

bayes_cv_tuner = BayesSearchCV(
    estimator=estimator,
    search_spaces=search_space,
    scoring="accuracy",
    cv=cv,
    n_jobs=-1,
    n_iter=n_iterations,
    verbose=0,
    refit=True,
)

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def print_status(optimal_result):
    """Shows the best parameters found and accuracy attained of the search so far."""
    models_tested = pd.DataFrame(bayes_cv_tuner.cv_results_)
    best_parameters_so_far = pd.Series(bayes_cv_tuner.best_params_)
    print(
        "Model #{}\nBest accuracy so far: {}\nBest parameters so far: {}\n".format(
            len(models_tested),
            np.round(bayes_cv_tuner.best_score_, 3),
            bayes_cv_tuner.best_params_,
        )
    )

    clf_type = bayes_cv_tuner.estimator.__class__.__name__
    models_tested.to_csv(clf_type + "_cv_results_summary.csv")


result = bayes_cv_tuner.fit(X, y, callback=print_status, groups=data.groups)
```

When I run this, everything's fine until it reaches model 10, where is returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-189-dc299c53649b>", line 1, in <module>
    result = bayes_cv_tuner.fit(X, y, callback=print_status, groups=data_nobands2.AGREEMENT_NUMBER2)

  File "C:\Users\CatKa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skopt\searchcv.py", line 694, in fit
    groups=groups, n_points=n_points_adjusted

  File "C:\Users\CatKa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skopt\searchcv.py", line 565, in _step
    params = optimizer.ask(n_points=n_points)

  File "C:\Users\CatKa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skopt\optimizer\optimizer.py", line 417, in ask
    opt._tell(x, y_lie)

  File "C:\Users\CatKa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skopt\optimizer\optimizer.py", line 553, in _tell
    n_samples=self.n_points, random_state=self.rng))

  File "C:\Users\CatKa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skopt\space\space.py", line 963, in transform
    columns[j] = self.dimensions[j].transform(columns[j])

  File "C:\Users\CatKa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skopt\space\space.py", line 162, in transform
    return self.transformer.transform(X)

  File "C:\Users\CatKa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skopt\space\transformers.py", line 304, in transform
    X = transformer.transform(X)

  File "C:\Users\CatKa\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skopt\space\transformers.py", line 251, in transform
    "be greater than %f" % self.low)

ValueError: All integer values shouldbe greater than 0.000000
```

I've obviously googled but didn't find anything useful. Any ideas?

Btw, just in case, there is no negative values in my dataset at all.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the exact same issue for a binary classification task.
After successive testing I identified the error was related to `scale_pos_weight`.

[from XGBoost documentation:](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html)

> **scale_pos_weight** [default=1]
>
> Control the balance of positive and negative weights, useful for unbalanced classes. A typical value to consider: sum(negative
> instances) / sum(positive instances). See Parameters Tuning for more
> discussion. Also, see Higgs Kaggle competition demo for examples: R,
> py1, py2, py3.

Knowing my data, I set manually this parameter.

In your case of multiclass classification I suggest you use the `weight` parameter when instantiating your data in `xgboost.DMatrix` as illustrated in [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/18823)